# Django keeps recreating the same migration file for ManyToManyField with default value

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I'm encountering a recurring issue in my Django project where Django keeps recreating the same migration file for a `ManyToManyField` with a default value set to `MyModel.objects.all`.

Each time I run `python manage.py makemigrations`, it generates a new migration file that keeps creates the same code but increment the dependencies only, even though the model hasn't changed.

When running `python manage.py migrate` it will show me:

```bash
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models in app(s): 'my_model' have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Here's an example of the migration code that keeps getting regenerated:

```
# 0016_alter_my_model_my_field_name_and_more.py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ("another_service", "0004_previous_migration"),
        ("this_service", "0015_alter_my_model_my_field_name_and_more"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name="my_model",
            name="my_field_name",
            field=models.ManyToManyField(
                default=django.db.models.manager.BaseManager.all,
                help_text="My field text help.",
                to="another_service.my_other_model",
            ),
        ),
    ]
```

The model and field are defined as this:

```
class MyModel(PolymorphicModel):
    ...
    my_field_name = models.ManyToManyField(
        "another_service.AnotherModel",
        default=AnotherModel.objects.all,
        help_text="My field text help.",
    )
    ...
```

How can I make `my_field_name` to have all items from my `AnotherModel` on database without have the `makemigrations` on infinite loop to recreate this?

Comment: This is because `ManyToManyFields` don't directly support a default value. You'll need to utilize probably the `post_save` signal to check if the field is empty then if it is add default values.